# How to stream repeated fields into bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the `tabledata().insertAll()`

here is some test data I'm trying to insert:

```
row = {
    'insertId': str(i*o),
    'json': {
        'meterId': i*o,
        'erfno': str(i),
        'latitude': '123123',
        'longitude': '123123',
        'address': str(random.randint(1, 100)) + 'foobar street',
        'readings': [
            {
                'read_at': time.time(),
                'usage': random.randrange(50, 500),
                'account': 'acc' + str(i*o)
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It gives me the error:

> array specified for non-repeated field

I wish to stream (and thus append to the repeated field) one record at a time of the 'readings' repeated field every minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot update an existing row. You cannot add to an existing row. You need to rethink this. Don't forget that BigQuery is append only.

You can have repeated fields in rows, but it must be declared as that in your schema.

In your situation, you need to create new rows with every reading. `reading` can be a record if you want to structure your data like that.

Comment: So it's not possible to append to a RECORD?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: The key phrase here is "BigQuery is append only." You can add additional rows to a repeated field if you first delete the parent row and then re-add the entire row with all of its repeated rows. I never try to update anything in BigQuery; instead, I delete large swaths of data by date and then re-add them.

Answer (score 1):

Correct! You should consider flatenning your table, inserting a new row for every new reading.